# Claim on structures of groups in elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

An old article makes the following claim.

[image]

This doesn't get a proof, so i suppose it must be easy. Is it a general property of abelian varieties of genus one or something more simple?

Comment: It is a curve of genus one and an abelian variety of dimension 1, both are equivalent but genus 2 curve and dimension 2 abelian variety are completely different. A genus one curve has to be an elliptic curve from the Riemann-Roch stuffs (the group law is given by the divisor class group) thus is suffices to show (say in characteristic $\ge 5$) that for $C:y^2=x^3+ax+b$ the degree of the $[n]$ endomorphism is $n^2$ and that $[n]$ is separable iff $p\nmid n$ to get your result. Proving those things is the purpose of Silverman's book.

Comment: One argument is that the property $\# E[n] =n^2$ of complex tori stays true (when $p\nmid n$) for curves over $\Bbb{F}_q$ because we have a bijective reduction $\bmod p$ map. The other is that if $G$ is an abelian group and for all $p\nmid n, \# G[n]=n^2$ then $G[n] \cong \Bbb{Z/nZ}\times \Bbb{Z/nZ}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your $k$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$.

The point is that for any $r > 0$, we have either $E[p^r] \simeq \mathbb Z/p^r\mathbb Z$ or $E[p^r]$ is trivial. Here $E[p^r]$ means the group of $p^r$-torsion points of $E$ in the algebraic closure of $k$. This is proved in Silverman's book.

In view of this, the $p$-Sylow of $E(k)$, being a subgroup of $E[p^r]$ for some $r$, must be cyclic. That's why we must have only one component $\mathbb Z/p^{h_p}\mathbb Z$.

For any other prime $l\neq p$, we know that $E[l^r] \simeq (\mathbb Z/l^r \mathbb Z)^2$, hence the $l$-Sylow can have one or two component(s), therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/l^{a_l}\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/l^{h_l - a_l}\mathbb Z$ for some integer $a_l$.

Comment: @reuns Yes... I didn't pay attention to this.

Comment: $E[p^r] \simeq \mathbb Z/p^r\mathbb Z$ is for non-supersingular curve, otherwise it is $E[p^r] = \{O\}$, it is never $\# E[p]=p^{2}$ because $[p] = \phi^*\phi$ with $\phi$ the Frobenius which is purely inseparable ie. $\deg_s(\phi)=1$ and since $\deg([p])=p^2$ then $\#E[p]=\deg_s([p])$ is $1$ or $p$, then $\# E[p^r] = \deg_s([p^r])=\deg_s(( \phi^* \phi)^r)=\deg_s((\phi^*)^r\phi^r)= \deg_s((\phi^*)^r))= \deg_s(\phi^*)^r=\deg_s([p])^r$ by checking the two cases $\phi^*$ separable or not.

Comment: Without any difficult computation we know $\deg([n])$ because the characteristic $p$ (equation and group law equation of the) curve is the reduction of a curve over (the integers of) a number field which is a complex torus whose $n$ torsion has $n^2$ points. If $p\nmid n$ then $p\nmid \deg([n])$ so $[n]$ is separable and $\#E[n]=\deg_s([n])=\deg([n])=n^2$.